# Why is AWS Athena Binary Format for Geospatial Data Different From PostGIS?

Tags: gis, geospatial, postgis, presto, amazon-athena

I am trying to convert some code from Postgres/PostGIS to AWS Athena. The existing code uses WKB for representing geospatial data, so I want to keep using that. However, AWS Athena appears to have a different binary format than Postgres/PostGIS:

- Postgres/PostGIS: `SELECT ENCODE(ST_POINT(-82.9988, 39.9612), 'hex')` returns `0101000000abcfd556ecbf54c02575029a08fb4340`, which is expected WKB.
- AWS Athena: `SELECT TO_HEX(ST_POINT(-82.9988, 39.9612))` returns `000000000101000000ABCFD556ECBF54C02575029A08FB4340`, which is identical except for four leading zero bytes.

What are these four leading zero bytes? Is AWS Athena's binary representation of geospatial data just different i.e. I should just prepend four zero bytes before insertion? Or is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: It seems that the leading four bytes are the SRID. I now need some mechanism to convert my data to include this I suppose.

Comment: FWIW, this no longer seems to be the case:
SELECT TO_HEX(ST_POINT(-82.9988, 39.9612)) no longer works at all, and 
SELECT TO_HEX(ST_ASBINARY(ST_POINT(-82.9988, 39.9612))) returns 
0101000000ABCFD556ECBF54C02575029A08FB4340

Answer (score 0):

I would go the "safe" way and convert the column to WKT via [`ST_AsText()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsText.html) in Postgres, then transfer it to Athena and then convert it back to geometry via [`ST_GEOMETRY_FROM_TEXT`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/geospatial-functions-list.html#constructors-functions).

Comment: Not technically an answer to the question, but that's what I ended up doing.

Comment: I've had issues in the past with invalid geometries arising out of a round trip from WKB -> WKT -> WKB

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `ST_AsHexEWKB()`?

```
SELECT ST_AsHexEWKB(ST_SetSRID(ST_POINT(-82.9988, 39.9612), 4326));
                    st_ashexewkb
----------------------------------------------------
 0101000020E6100000ABCFD556ECBF54C02575029A08FB4340
```

Comment: Unfortunately, ST_AsHexEWKB() is not a registered function for now on AWS Athena.